# Acting on a date in batch

Tags: date, batch-file

I am looking for a way to add an amount, say 8, to a variable every Tuesday automatically. I have looked at several websites but have not been able to find my answer. The simpler the better

Answer (score 1):

Create a Trigger(every Tueasday) in Windows Task Scheduler which starts a program. The programm could add '8' to a var. You could save the varaible in a .txt. Thats pretty easy in batch.